# Sending an email via perl script

Tags: perl, email, module

I am following a course of Perl and have received a task to send myself an email from  perl@perlrocks using [Mail::Sendmail](http://search.cpan.org/~mivkovic/Mail-Sendmail/Sendmail.pm) module.

Though I have read the documentation, I still don't understand how to do it. For example, I use gmail as my normal email, should I configure gmail as the smpt protocol in the script? Could you please give me a hint on how to start?

Comment: What operating system are you working on? if on Linux/Unix then you could/should be configured fine. If you are on Windows, then you will most likely have to do some extra configuration. Have you tried tutorials like: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_sending_email.htm?

Comment: I am working on OS x. Yes, thank you, I have checked this tutorial but it doesn't use Mail::Sendmail module. I am still feel stuck as I don't understand how to configure the sending server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your environment. If you're running the script on a Linux server, just make sure the `sendmail` utility is installed (most distributions have it pre-installed). If you're on a non-Linux machine, install a mailserver on it or use an external SMTP server.

Although this specific mail module [does not support SMTP authentication](http://search.cpan.org/~mivkovic/Mail-Sendmail/Sendmail.pm#LIMITATIONS), which most external SMTP servers (like Google/Gmail) do require. But if you have a mailserver that does always allow SMTP connections from the machine your Perl script runs on, it can be as simple as:

```
use Mail::Sendmail qw(sendmail %mailcfg);

%mail = ( To      => 'you@example.com',
          From    => 'me@example.com',
          Message => "Hello world!"
);

$mailcfg{smtp} = [qw(smtp.example.com)];

sendmail(%mail) or die $Mail::Sendmail::error;
```

That will set `smtp.example.com` as e-mail server. (or you can skip that entire line if you *do* have a localhost mailserver, which is the default).